# Changing inner control as result of a event

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, controls, page-lifecycle

I have a composite control like:

```
class MyControl : CompositeControl {
   private Control _control1;
   private Control _control2;

   public bool RenderControl2 { get; set; }

   /* Constructor to initialize controls*/

    protected override void CreateChildControls(){
       if(RenderControl2){
           Controls.Add(_control2);
       }else{
           Controls.Add(_control1);
       }           
    }        
}
```

This works fine in scenarios where the value of RenderControl2 is set during Page_Init().

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!Page.IsPostBack){
       myControl.RenderControl2 = MyMagicFucntion();
    }
    /* Works also when in Postback, but not required since the control keeps it state and only need to change state in the scenario below.*/
}
```

However, now we would like to set the value as a result of an event

```
protected void otherDropDow_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myControl.RenderControl2 = otherDropDown.SelectedValue == "My Magic String";
}
```

This does not work since the control already executed CreateChildControls by the time the event fired. (Well, it does work during the next postback... :( )

I have tried to move the logic to the OnDataBinding event of the control. But this seems to have no impact on how the control actually show on the page.

```
/* DOES NOT RESOLVE THE ISSUE */
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e){  
   base.OnDataBinding(e);
   /* _renderControl2HasChanged is set when RenderControl2 changes value          
   */
   if(_renderControl2HasChanged)
      if(RenderControl2){
          Controls.Remove(_control1);
          Controls.Add(_control2);
      }else{
          Controls.Remove(_control2);
          Controls.Add(_control1);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the decision which control to display in `CreateChildControls`, you could evaluate the flag in `OnPreRender` and only change the visibility of the child controls, e.g.:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
   Controls.Add(_control1);
   Controls.Add(_control2);
}     

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   _control1.Visible = !RenderControl2;
   _control2.Visible = RenderControl2;
}
```

In addition, you should save the value of `RenderControl2` in the control state as described [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.savecontrolstate?view=netframework-4.7.2). This way it will be persisted across postbacks.